# Use type name for indexer in interface

Tags: typescript, interface, indexer

### Problem in Abstract

I have 2 groups of types that I'd like to relate to each other.

```
// Group A
interface Hello { ... }
interface Foo { ... }

// Group B
interface World { ... }
interface Bar { ... }
```

To do this, I'm building a third interface that acts as a look-up from one type to another:

```
interface LookupMap {
  Hello: World;
  Foo: Bar;
}
```

Ultimately I'd like to be able get from one type to the other using one interface as an indexer for `LookupMap` (similar to how strings and numbers can be used to look up types in indexed object literals):

```
type AltType<T> = LookupMap<T>;

const altHello: AltType<Hello> = ...; // should be of type World
const altFoo: AltType<Foo> = ...;     // should be of type Bar
```

This doesn't work - seems types can't be used as indexers like that.

---

### Actual Use Case

I'm trying to add some better typing to Immutable.js.

**There's some gnarly looking code below this point.**  If you've got a solution already you're probs okay without reading all of this...

Immutable objects have a lot of useful functions on them, for the sake of argument let's just try and add typing to `Map.get`.

As long as all of your values are primitive, it's actually pretty easy:

```
interface Immutalizer<MUTABLE_TYPE> extends Immutable.Map<keyof MUTABLE_TYPE, MUTABLE_TYPE[keyof MUTABLE_TYPE]> {
  get<PROP_NAME extends keyof MUTABLE_TYPE>(prop: PROP_NAME, notSetValue?: MUTABLE_TYPE[PROP_NAME]): MUTABLE_TYPE[PROP_NAME];
}

interface MyInterface {
  hello: boolean;
  world: string;
  foo: number;
  bar: symbol;
}

interface MyImmutableInterface extends Immutalizer<MyInterface> {};

const myObject: MyImmutableInterface = Immutable.fromJS(...);
myObject.get("hello"); // boolean
myObject.get("world"); // string
myObject.get("foo");   // number
myObject.get("bar");   // symbol
```

Diving deeper, if some of our props are complex objects, we have to provide a second type to `Immutalizer` to give it some context:

```
interface Immutalizer<
  MUTABLE_TYPE,
  COMPLEX_OBJECT_KEYMAP extends { [PROP_NAME in keyof MUTABLE_TYPE]: any } = MUTABLE_TYPE
> extends Immutable.Map<
  keyof MUTABLE_TYPE,
  COMPLEX_OBJECT_KEYMAP[keyof MUTABLE_TYPE]
> {
  get<PROP_NAME extends keyof MUTABLE_TYPE>(prop: PROP_NAME, notSetValue?: COMPLEX_OBJECT_KEYMAP[PROP_NAME]): COMPLEX_OBJECT_KEYMAP[PROP_NAME];
}


interface Hello {
  foo: string;
  bar: World;
}

interface World {
  a: number;
  b: symbol;
}

interface ImmutableHello extends Immutalizer<Hello, {
  foo: string;
  bar: ImmutableWorld;
}> {};

interface ImmutableWorld extends Immutalizer<World> {}; // this one is all primitives so the default type will cover it

const myObject: ImmutableHello = Immutable.fromJS(...);
myObject.get("bar");          // ImmutableWorld
myObject.get("foo");          // string
myObject.get("bar").get("a"); // number
myObject.get("bar").get("b"); // symbol
```

This is a LOT of busy work, and it only gets worse the deeper your object tree goes - so I worked out an alternate solution that's just *oh so close* to working, but isn't quite there yet:

```
type Primitive = string | number | boolean | symbol | String | Number | Boolean | Symbol;
type PrimitiveSwitch<PROP_TYPE, IMMUTALIZER_MAP extends ImmutalizerMap> =
  PROP_TYPE extends Primitive ?
  PROP_TYPE :
  IMMUTALIZER_MAP[PROP_TYPE]; // TYPE ERROR: Type 'PROP_TYPE' cannot be used to index type 'IMMUTALIZER_MAP'.
interface ImmutalizerMap { [mutableType: string]: Immutalizer<any, this> }

interface Immutalizer<MUTABLE_TYPE, IMMUTALIZER_MAP extends ImmutalizerMap> {
  get<PROP_NAME extends keyof MUTABLE_TYPE>(
    prop: PROP_NAME,
    notSetValue?: PrimitiveSwitch<MUTABLE_TYPE[PROP_NAME], IMMUTALIZER_MAP>
  ): PrimitiveSwitch<MUTABLE_TYPE[PROP_NAME], IMMUTALIZER_MAP>;
}


export interface Hello {
  foo: string;
  bar: World;
}

export interface World {
  a: number;
  b: symbol;
}

interface ImmutableHello extends Immutalizer<Hello, ImmutalizerMap> { }
interface ImmutableWorld extends Immutalizer<World, ImmutalizerMap> { }

interface MyImmutalizerMap {
  Hello: ImmutableHello;
  World: ImmutableWorld;
}

const hello: ImmutableHello = Immutable.fromJS(...);

hello.get("foo"); // string
hello.get("bar"); // unknown (should be ImmutableWorld)
```

The `Immutalizer` bit itself is a bit rough to read, but using it is now a (theoretical) breeze:

- Maintain a mapping of all types and their associated immutable types.
- Form immutable types using `Immutalizer` by passing in the base-type and the `ImmutalizerMap` it belongs to
- `Immutalizer` does the rest, using `PrimitiveSwitch` to determine if any given type needs to be looked up in the `ImmutalizerMap` or not.

But as stated in the abstract version above, accessing `IMMUTALIZER_MAP[PROP_TYPE]` in `PrimitiveSwitch` triggers a type error: `Type 'PROP_TYPE' cannot be used to index type 'IMMUTALIZER_MAP'.`

---

### Question

**Can an interface (name) be used as indexers in other interfaces?**  Is there a better solution to Immutable typing?

Answer (score 0):

Well not an answer to the question of indexers, I did find a more complete solution to adding typing to Immutable.js using recursion:

```
type Primitive = string | number | boolean | symbol | String | Number | Boolean | Symbol;

type PrimitiveSwitch<MUTABLE_TYPE, PROP_NAME extends keyof MUTABLE_TYPE> = MUTABLE_TYPE[PROP_NAME] extends Primitive ? MUTABLE_TYPE[PROP_NAME] : Immutalizer<MUTABLE_TYPE[PROP_NAME]>

interface Immutalizer<MUTABLE_TYPE> extends Immutable.Map<keyof MUTABLE_TYPE, Immutalizer<MUTABLE_TYPE[keyof MUTABLE_TYPE]> | MUTABLE_TYPE[keyof MUTABLE_TYPE]> {
  get<PROP_NAME extends keyof MUTABLE_TYPE>(prop: PROP_NAME, notSetValue?: PrimitiveSwitch<MUTABLE_TYPE, PROP_NAME>): PrimitiveSwitch<MUTABLE_TYPE, PROP_NAME>
}

interface Hello {
  foo: string;
  bar: World;
}

interface World {
  a: number;
  b: symbol;
}

interface ImmutableHello extends Immutalizer<Hello> { };
interface ImmutableWorld extends Immutalizer<World> { };

let hello: ImmutableHello = Immutable.fromJS({});
let world: ImmutableWorld = hello.get("bar");

hello.get("bar").get("b"); // symbol
world.get("b");            // symbol
```

You lose the names of the interfaces (`hello.get("bar")` returns `Immutalizer<World>` instead of `ImmutableWorld`) but the types are still compatible.